# Is using su to drop root in shell scripts a security risk?

Tags: security, permissions, bash, root

When searching for how to drop root permissions in shell scripts, I often see answers using `su`. However, when you're done using `su` you can just type `logout` and be back at the shell of the original user. I have a bash script running as root, and I do this at the end:

```
exec su -c "external_com" - muser
```

This results in the following process tree:

```
  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
    1 root       20   0 37352  2500  2192 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.02 su -c external_com
    5 muser      20   0 85548  6292  5156 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.47 └─ external_com
   13 muser      20   0 85548  6292  5156 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.35    ├─ external_com
   12 muser      20   0 85548  6292  5156 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.02    ├─ external_com
```

I cannot control `external_com`, and it doesn't call setuid internally. It presents a web interface that's public to the world. If someone *somehow* gets a console through a security hole in the web interface, could they just call `logout` and be a root user?

EDIT: If I'm reading correctly, a better approach is to just run the script as `muser` and allow `muser` to sudo the few commands it needs. I'd still like an answer to this question though, as it's valuable information to know :)

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not a thing to be concerned about.

If someone obtained a shell as a result of a security hole in external_com, then all they could do is run commands as muser.  If they exited that shell (with logout), then that's the end of that shell process; they don't end up back as root.  When external_com ends, the process/script that started it will exit (because you did an 'exec')

Comment: Just a comment, unrelated to the security-related nature of the question. You should rather use "runuser" for this purpose rather than "su".